# Beamer bibliography item not shown with Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, biblatex, margins

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \nocite{padhye}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography item symbol is barely shown when using Madrid Theme:

[image]

If I remove the Madrid theme then it shows correctly:

[image]

Is it possible to show the bibliography item symbol correctly when using Madrid theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *trouble* happens with *all* themes that use the `infolines` *outer theme* (i.e AnnArbor, Boadilla, CambridgeUS, EastLansing and Madrid) because the left margin is very small. This makes the label is hidden.

A possible solution (*with unknown effects*) is extend the margin a bit with

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.5em}
```

Try

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.5em}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text
  \nocite{padhye}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```